# How can I evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_n^\infty \frac{n^2 \arctan {\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2+n^2}\ dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I'm here wondering if this integral that our math teacher gave us (students) is even possible to evaluate? I just started to study real analysis so I find this very disturbing. Here you go, and if anyone has any idea I will be very grateful.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_n^\infty \frac{n^2 \arctan {\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2+n^2}\ dx$$

Comment: Did you mean $\tan$ or $\arctan$ when you typed \atan?

Comment: Arctan, but I don't know to use this latex well :/

Comment: See this [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write equations in a more readable way.

Comment: @RonaldoNazario, sorry for the messed up. If you look at Robjohn's answer, you really need to know Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem or some sort like that.

Comment: Robjohn's answer is simple, nice, elegant and effective ! This is the one you must consider.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The change of variables $x\mapsto nx$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^\infty\frac{n^2\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)}{x^2+n^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\frac{n\arctan\left(\frac1{nx}\right)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\int_1^\infty\frac{\frac1x}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\int_1^\infty\left(\frac1x-\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_1^n\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_1^n\frac x{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag4\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(n)-\frac12\log\left(\frac{n^2+1}2\right)\right)\tag5\\[3pt]
&=\frac12\log(2)\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto nx$
$(2)$: $0\le\frac1x-n\arctan\left(\frac1{nx}\right)\le\frac1{3n^2x^3}$; therefore, $0\le(2)-(1)\le\frac1{12n^2}$
$(3)$: partial fractions
$(4)$: write the improper integral as a limit
$(5)$: evaluate the integrals
$(6)$: evaluate the limit

Comment: As usual, simpler and nice !

Comment: OP has stated in my comment box that he is more likely to use anything without Dominated, just usual improper integral, do you think it is possible?

Comment: @user284331 I think just proving a simple version of dominated convergence theorem is fine here. All the techniques involved should already be covered by a first-year course in mathematical analysis.

Comment: Since $$\begin{align}x-\arctan(x) &=\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\ &\le\int_0^x t^2\,\mathrm{d}t\\ &=\frac{x^3}3\end{align}$$ we have $\frac1x-n\arctan\left(\frac1{nx}\right)\le\frac1{3n^2x^3}$ so the difference of the limit of the integral and the integral of the limit  is less than $$\begin{align}\int_1^\infty\frac{\frac1{3n^2x^3}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x &\le\frac1{3n^2}\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^5}\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\frac1{12n^2}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 7):

**Sorry for overlooking some constant, the following is for the integral $\displaystyle\int_{n}^{\infty}\dfrac{n\tan^{-1}(1/x)}{x^{2}+n^{2}}dx$, the integral in question will be addressed in the second part.**

By change of variable $u=x/n$, then the integral is 
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(1/(nu))}{1+u^{2}}du.
\end{align*}
But 
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+u^{2}}du<\infty
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(1/(nu))}{1+u^{2}}\leq\dfrac{\tan^{-1}1}{1+u^{2}}
\end{align*}
for all $u\geq 1$, $n\geq 1$, use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude that the limit is zero.

It seems that there is an elementary answer.

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(1/(nu))}{1+u^{2}}du\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\tan^{-1}u\tan^{-1}(1/(nu))\bigg|_{u=1}^{u=\infty}+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}u}{1+(1/(nu))^{2}}\dfrac{1}{nu^{2}}du\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}u}{n^{2}u^{2}+1}du,
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
n\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}u^{2}+1}du&=\int_{n}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{v^{2}+1}dv\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}n\\
&\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
However,
\begin{align*}
n\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}u}{n^{2}u^{2}+1}du\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}\cdot n\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}u^{2}+1}du.
\end{align*}

**For the integral in question:**

So the integral is $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n\tan^{-1}(1/(nu))}{1+u^{2}}$, and we have $n\tan^{-1}(1/(nu))\rightarrow(1/u)$ by L'Hopital rule or some sort, and note that $\tan^{-1}v$ behaves like $v$ for small $|v|$.

And in fact, one deduces using Taylor formula or some sort that $n\tan^{-1}(1/(nu))\leq 1/u$, and that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{u(1+u^{2})}\leq\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+u^{2}}du<\infty,
\end{align*}
so Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem implies that the limit in question is then
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{u(1+u^{2})}du&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{u}-\dfrac{1}{1+u^{2}}\right)du\\
&=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\left(\log u\bigg|_{u=1}^{u=M}-\dfrac{1}{2}\log(1+u^{2})\bigg|_{u=1}^{u=M}\right)\\
&=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\log 2+\log\dfrac{M}{\sqrt{1+M^{2}}}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\log 2+\log 1\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\log 2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Seeing as the tag is riemann-integration, I'm not convinced standard DCT is within scope. (Though of course for these functions, the riemann and lebesgue integrals coincide so it's still valid)

Comment: But OP stated that he is learning real analysis?

Comment: Real analysis may still involve the riemann integral exclusively

Comment: I see. Then just wait for other answer, I don't have without Lebesgue one.

Comment: We haven't  mentioned Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem on class, so I truly didn't fully understand your answer, but while I was trying to solve this integral I made first two steps of your proof and then I get stuck

Comment: You are telling that the answer is zero?

Comment: Yes, the answer is zero.

Comment: Intuitively, I could understand, but can you explain it a bit simpler, without that LDC theorem, or with some easy to understand explanation of it. P.S. I'm a 19 years old student who just started (before 2 months) studying real analysis. Thanks for answer, anyway!

Comment: Okay, I have another answer.

Comment: @RonaldoNazario I have an answer which should be within scope for you.

Comment: Excuse me, but haven't you forgot n after that u=x/n step? Because dx=n*du, instead of dx=du

Comment: Your right, I overlook some $n$ there.

Comment: I have the feeling that the limit is $\frac 12 \log(2)$. Would you please check my answer since I may be wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**  This was intended to finish a previous answer by user284331, which contained an error I failed to spot. I'll keep this because it demonstrates a useful technique, but this is solving the wrong integral. Please refer to the other answers instead.

---

I'll finish off the other answer using theorems involving the Riemann integral only for completeness - Lebesgue's dominated convergence may not be in the scope of your course (but is the natural way to solve this problem).

We have the sequence $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan \frac{1}{nu}}{1+u^2} \, du$$
and observe the functions $f_n(u) = \frac{\arctan \frac{1}{nu}}{1+u^2}$ converge uniformly to $0$. We would like to show convergence of the integrals to $0$. You will likely come across the theorem that for a sequence of uniformly convergent functions on a bounded interval, the limit of the integrals is the integral of the limit. But here, the issue is that the functions are not defined on a bounded interval.

So, instead split into two regions. We have that $f_n \leq \frac{\arctan 1}{1+u^2}$ for all $n$, and this is an integrable function. So, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is some $c$ such that
$$\int_c^\infty \frac{\arctan 1}{1+u^2} \, du < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
but then
$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty f_n(u)\, du &= \int_0^c f_n(u)\, du + \int_c^\infty f_n(u)\, du \\
&\leq c \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2c} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon\end{align}$$
by choosing $n$ such that $\|f_n(u)\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2c}$, which exists by uniform convergence.

So, the limit is 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this should be in the scope of my course, but at the moment I'm not so familiar with this. It's confusing my for a bit, probably because I just started to studying this field of math. Anyway, thanks for the answer, it's a bit vividly now.

Comment: Sure, let me know if there's any part I can clarify.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I do really appreciate your effort,but it looks like I'll need to study analysis much more (which I find really interesting and exciting) to truly understand all of your proof. At the other hand, I do understood user284331's answer, so I'm grateful to both of you.

Comment: @B.Mehta, thanks for your compliment, and I have combined my two answers, it is better not to separate.

Comment: I have the feeling that the limit is $\frac 12 \log(2)$. Would you please check my answer since I may be wrong ?

Comment: No worry, your right. Just that I missed some $n$, and I believe B. Mehta looked up my substitution, and then addressing the rest issue.

Comment: @B.Mehta, please do not delete your answer, just to declare that we are addressing different integral, because there is a good inequality estimate in your reasoning, this is worth to be demonstrated here.

Comment: Thank you both for this!

Answer (score 5):

*I may be totally wrong but I have the feeling that the limit is not $0$.*

If you look [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.4983.pdf), you will find (Theorem II.1) very nice bounds for $\tan^{-1}(y)$
$$\frac{y}{\frac{4}{\pi
   ^2}+\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\right)^2+\frac{4 y^2}{\pi ^2}}} < \tan^{-1}(x) <\frac{y}{1-\frac{6}{\pi ^2}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{6}{\pi ^2}\right)^2+\frac{4 y^2}{\pi ^2}}}$$ Using $y=\frac 1x$, we face, for each bound, the problem of
$$I=\int \frac{n^2}{\left(n^2+x^2\right) \left(a x+\sqrt{b^2 x^2+c}\right)}\,dx$$ which is tedious but doable (I shall not write the expressions here, at least for the time being).

Computing from $I$ $$J=\int_n^\infty \frac{n^2}{\left(n^2+x^2\right) \left(a x+\sqrt{b^2 x^2+c}\right)}\,dx$$ and developing as Taylor series for infinitely large values of $n$, we get for the left bound
$$J=\frac{\log (2)}{2}+\frac{\log (2)-1}{\left(\pi ^2-4\right) n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ and for the right bound
$$J=\frac{\log (2)}{2}+\frac{\log (2)-1}{6 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

So, using the squeeze theorem, the limit looks to be $\frac{1}{2}\log (2)$.

For a sanity check, let $n=10^k$ and numerical integration of the given function leads to
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \text{result} \\
 1 & 0.346064090433349 \\
 2 & 0.346568476259452 \\
 3 & 0.346573539137855 \\
 4 & 0.346573589768551 \\
 5 & 0.346573590274858 \\
 6 & 0.346573590279922 \\
 7 & 0.346573590279972 \\
 8 & 0.346573590279973 \\
 9 & 0.346573590279973
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Your right, because I overlook for another $n$.

Comment: Claudi Leibovici, your answer is real treasure, thanks. Very clearly. What program do you use for numeric integration?

Comment: @RonaldoNazario. *real treasure*, not at all (or you are kidding me). I have a bunch of programs of mine for that (developed over the last 60 years for very specific problems)..

Comment: Well, as a young student I'm very amazed. I wanted to test this integral with some numeric integration, but I didn't know which software to use

Comment: Be lazy (it is not a sin) and use Wolfram Alpha and type **integrate 10^6 tan(1/x)/(10^6+x^2) from x=10^3 to infinity** to get $\approx 0.346574$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{n}^{\infty}{n^{2}\arctan\pars{1/x} \over x^{2} + n^{2}}
\,\dd x &
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\,\,\,
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1/n}{\arctan\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1/n^{2}}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1/n}{x \over x^{2} + 1/n^{2}}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{1/n}{\arctan\pars{x} - x \over x^{2} + 1/n^{2}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}

> With $\ds{0 < x < 1/n}$, note that $\ds{\exists\ \xi \mid 0 < \xi < x}$ which satisfies
>   
>   $\ds{\verts{\arctan\pars{x} - x} = x\,{\xi^{2} \over 1 + \xi^{2}} < {1 \over n^{3}}}$ such that

$$
0 < \verts{\int_{0}^{1/n}{\arctan\pars{x} - x \over x^{2} + 1/n^{2}}\,\dd x} <
{1 \over n^{3}}\verts{\int_{0}^{1/n}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1/n^{2}}} =
{1 \over n^{3}}\,{n\pi \over 4}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\, {\large 0}
$$

---

Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{n}^{\infty}{n^{2}\arctan\pars{1/x} \over x^{2} + n^{2}}
\,\dd x &
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1/n}{x \over x^{2} + 1/n^{2}}\,\dd x =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1/n^{2} + 1/n^{2} \over 1/n^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = \bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}} \approx 0.3466
\end{align}